# Ubuntu becomes really slow after a while

Tags: drivers, games, additional-drivers

I will start by saying that i have been using Ubuntu for only a few days and before this OS i had windows 7. Now i'm using ubuntu 16.04 lts 
After i start watching a movie or playing a simple game the system starts lagging very hard, it starts going in slow-motion. From what i have read online, Ubuntu should be faster than windows because it uses less resources but for some reason, a game i could play on windows "Terraria" which by the way is supported on Linux, i can't play it on Ubuntu because everything starts going in slow motion, even if i kill the process.
I went to see the additional drivers and i only have one option 
"Unknown:Unknown"
Using processor microcode firmware for intel CPUs from intel-microcode (proprietary), which i have checked
and "Do not use the device"
.

Comment: It seems your laptop hardware is not compatible(as you are saying it is a fresh install). Linux’s hardware support is better than ever, but you still can’t take it for granted. Not every laptop and desktop  will work perfectly with Linux.

Comment: What's your swappiness? Run `sysctl vm.swappiness` as root to get it.